# Unable to view timeslots in MAC OS using laravel

Tags: javascript

I am unable to choose a time slot in Mac. In windows, it is working fine.
I have tried changing the codes in my visual studio.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/calendar/read_schedule/'+doctor_id,
                data: {
                    date: info.event.start.toLocaleDateString(),
                },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response.success){
                        $('#add-event select[name="time-slot"]').html('');
                        let option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.value = 0;
                        option.innerHTML = "Pick a time slot";
                        $('#add-event select[name="time-slot"]').append(option);
                        
                        response.schedule.forEach(element => {
                            let option = document.createElement("option");
                            option.value = element.id;

                            if (time > element.t_start && date < today)
                                $(this).prop("hidden", true);

                            else{
                            option.innerHTML = element.t_start + ' - ' + element.t_end
                            $('#add-event select[name="time-slot"]').append(option);
    
                            };
                           
                        });
```

Comment: Maybe it's a browser issue problem. In windows, you use `chrome` browser and in MAC you use `safari`. That's why the problem occurs

Comment: `info.event.start.toLocaleDateString()` is also a suspect since the locale date string may be of a completely different format and at a different timezone between Windows and Mac

Comment: @A.ANoman yes tested that . Chrome on Mac does not work and works on safari of the 10.13.6 version.For the latest version it does not work as well

Comment: @apokryfos thank you.ANy suggestion on what to use for MAC?

Comment: If you're sending it to a server then you probably should be using `.toISOString()`

Comment: @KeerthishaVasudevan, You have to use jquery or javascript plugin for all browser

Comment: i have found the solution to this, date: info.event.start.toDateString('en-us'). Works perfectly for both windows and mac

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue by doing this.Thanks guys.

date: info.event.start.toDateString('en-us')